# React and Openlayers. Ok, but why?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I am writing a fairly complex Openlayers map application. I am considering implementing React with the application but I am wondering what added benefit it would bring, especially since openlayers has so many built in objects, methods, “stores” etc. Writing React code to access and control those objects etc would be a lot more code. Is it worth it in terms of performance or granularity? (Openlayers is already pretty granular).

Comment: React is a view library. OpenLayers already handles a map view for you. I don't see a reason why you would try and control OL with React unless it's part of a larger app.

Comment: Yes my thoughts exactly. But maybe there is a good reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenLayers** handles map view as *@estacks* said , that is true. There is no reason to use react to handle map view.

But it may not be just map things on your page.

For example; I am working on a map page, it has:

- three different data filter modal
- one feture detail modal
- one modal for property editing
- one collapseble div to show data

I use [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) to handle this features. I am struggling to do that, it is very hard for me.

**[React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)** or another [javascript library for building interfaces](https://www.slant.co/topics/3286/~javascript-libraries-for-building-a-ui) helps to achieve this complexity.

Comment: Thanks. That is true, but I am wondering more about map specific functionality.